# Masking user input passwords

Tags: ruby, cyclomatic-complexity

I have a method that accepts user input. Additionally, it masks passwords then the input is a password. It also bypasses the prompt of if an env variable supplies the needed input.

Apparently, my code needs refactoring, but how?

```
def self.gets(args)
  array = []
  args.each do |arg|
    print "#{arg.to_s.capitalize}: "
    if ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
      array.push ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
    else
      if arg.to_s=~/password/
        array.push STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
      else
        array.push STDIN.gets.chomp
      end
    end
    print "\n"
  end
  array
end
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading @user1777136 s answer, I came up with this

```
module Awesome
  # Has methods that are similar to but extended versions                                                        
  # of core ruby methods                                                                                         
  module Extensions
    # Get multipe inputs from user                                                                               
    # Masks passwords if detected                                                                                
    # Bypasses prompt when ENV variables present                                                                 
    def self.mgets(names)
      names.map do |name|
        sgets(name)
      end
    end

    # single gets                                                                                                
    def self.sgets(name)
      print "#{name.to_s.capitalize}: "
      return env_sgets(name) if ENV['AWESOME_' + name.to_s.upcase]
      return secure_sgets if name.match?(/password/)
      STDIN.gets.chomp
    end

    # get from env variable                                                                                      
    def self.env_sgets(name)
      ENV['AWESOME_' + name.to_s.upcase]
    end

    # secure gets from stdin                                                                                     
    def self.secure_sgets
      STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice one! Thats pretty clear now. Academically speaking, you could put the stuff into a class instead of a module and instantiate it with `STDIN` and `ENV` in order to abstract yourself from those two globals.

Answer (score 0):

Granted I know nothing about the inputs and so on. But I see at least two responsibilities of the method:

1. Printing something
2. Returning an array of something

You might want to split the loop accordingly, which could give you:

```
def self.gets(args)
  array = []
  args.each do |arg|
    print "#{arg.to_s.capitalize}: "
    print "\n"
  end
  args.each do |arg|
    if ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
      array.push ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
    else
      if arg.to_s=~/password/
        array.push STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
      else
        array.push STDIN.gets.chomp
      end
    end
  end
  array
end
```

This can help us further down the line. Nested `if, if, else` can be refactored to `elsif`. Rubocop can also tell you this. So the following will remove one level of nesting:

```
def self.gets(args)
  array = []
  args.each do |arg|
    print "#{arg.to_s.capitalize}: "
    print "\n"
  end
  args.each do |arg|
    if ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
      array.push ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
    elsif arg.to_s=~/password/
      array.push STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
    else
      array.push STDIN.gets.chomp
    end
  end
  array
end
```

Furthermore it looks like we are *always* returning something from the second loop. So building a new "collector" array (which has a not so great name of `array`) can be avoided. Which gives us:

```
def self.gets(args)
  args.each do |arg|
    print "#{arg.to_s.capitalize}: "
    print "\n"
  end
  args.map do |arg|
    if ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
      return ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
    elsif arg.to_s=~/password/
      return STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
    else
      return STDIN.gets.chomp
    end
  end
end
```

Since Ruby will return the last evaluated thing in the method and we are mentioning `args` twice now we can even chain this:

```
def self.gets(args)
  args
    .each { |arg| print "#{arg.to_s.capitalize}: \n" }
    .map do |arg|
      if ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
        return ENV['AWESOMEAPP_'+arg.to_s.upcase]
      elsif arg.to_s=~/password/
        return STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
      else
        return STDIN.gets.chomp
      end
    end
end
```

Finishing this off by extracting a method or two will lead us to:

```
def self.gets(args)
  args
    .each(&:print_arg)
    .map(&:read_arg)
end

def print_arg(arg)
  print "#{arg.to_s.capitalize}: \n"
end

def read_arg(arg)
  if ENV["AWESOMEAPP_#{arg.to_s.upcase}"]
    ENV["AWESOMEAPP_#{arg.to_s.upcase}"]
  elsif arg.to_s =~ /password/
    STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
  else
    STDIN.gets.chomp
  end
end
```

Now I am pretty sure I have broken your code, but this can give you an insight into what you could do.

Comment: you certainly broke the behavior, but your use if maps gives me some inspiration

Comment: the `print "#{arg.to_s.capitalize}: "` has to happen just before gets, because it's a prompt.   IF we have ten prompts, we shouldn't batch print, as I said the prompt should print and then gets